# Prime number function loop mistake

Tags: python, function, loops, primes

I have been told that this code for finding a prime number is wrong. Could anyone explain why? It works for at least the first 100 numbers.

```
    if x<2:
        return 'It is neither prime nor composite'
    elif x==2 or x==3:
        return 'It is a prime number'
    else:
        for i in range(2,int(x**0.5)+1):
            print(i)
            if x%i==0 :
                
                return 'It is not a prime number'
                break
        else:
            return 'It is a prime number'
```

Comment: Can you explain why not Riccardo? The logic looks okay to me, but maybe I'm missing something obvious. Note that the input is a single number (x) and the output is whether it is prime or not

Comment: @shravya, the person who told you it was wrong, did they give any reasons? Is it maybe that the requirements were different, were you expected to list all primes in a given range?

Comment: Exactly - I'm arguing the case that it appears correct to me - Riccardo said that the function failed for input 33 but I think he may have removed that comment now!

Comment: Now he has removed all his comments leaving mine without any context - I'll remove mine to avoid confusion - sorry @interjay, now your comment doesn't have context, it's why deleting comments without warning is a bit of a pain

Comment: @Shrvya, maybe this line - *for i in range(```3```, int(n ** 0.5)+1, 2):*   Why not starting with 3 in the range?  Because it will save a lot of computations...

Comment: @DanielHao If we start with 3, we wont be able to use the function for 4.

Comment: Why you care about *4*? It's 2's multiple and cannot be a prime. By definition. And this way will save lots of unnecessary computation

Answer (score 1):

I've tested your function with 1,000,000 integers, starting from 2, by comparing your results with ones from dedicated function from `sympy` library.

```py
import sympy

def prime(x):
    if x<2:
        return False
    elif x==2 or x==3:
        return True
    else:
        for i in range(2,int(x**0.5)+1):
            # print(i)
            if x%i==0 :
                return False
                # break  # not necessary, "return" above exits anyway
        else:
            return True

success = 0
fail = 0
for i in range(2, 1000002):
    if prime(i) != sympy.isprime(i):
        print(i)
        fail += 1
    else:
        success += 1
print(f'SUCCESSES: {success}\nFAILURES: {fail}')
```

Output:

```
SUCCESSES: 1000000
FAILURES: 0
```

You function seems to work with no issues

Comment: They said the answers might be right because I got lucky, but that there was something wrong with the logic. The way the decision is being made inside the loop.

Comment: I just realised that the 2nd else in the code is unnecessary. That can directly be replaced with the return and it would still work. So the code has some redundant parts, but I still don't know why it is wrong logically.

Comment: ^^^ Please see my comments.  That's prob. the only place I can think of, other than the *else*.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, it was meant not incorrectness, but inefficiency of the code. I would write differently:

```
def prime(n):
    if n < 3 or n % 2 == 0:
        return n == 2
    d = 3
    while d**2 <= n:
        if n % d == 0:
            return False
        d += 2
    return True

print(*filter(prime, range(101)))
```

Comment: It wasn't about efficiency. They said the logic was wrong. Something about the way the decision is made inside the for loop.